# What differences between populate and create methods in DBIx::Class?

Tags: database, perl, dbix-class

Could someone explain in which cases I have to use `create` or `populate` methods on ResultSet in DBIx::Class? And what differences between each other if everyone is used to insert some data to database?

**UPD**
For example. I have to insert some data to table1. There are create and populate methods for it. So I have to use `create` if there are any relationships otherwise I have to use `populate`, aren't there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create inserts one row (and possibly associated rows in other tables). Populate inserts multiple rows.

Comment: are multiple rows inserted only in one table? Could you give some examples to illustrate it?

Comment: you can use DBIC_TRACE and see an example yourself

Comment: The DBIx::Class reference docs for populate have examples: https://metacpan.org/module/DBIx::Class::ResultSet#populate

Comment: @abraxxa I read docs and mans about it but I want to see how these two methods are distinguished by the example.
Try to explain what I want. I have to insert some data to table1. There are `create` and `populate` methods for it. So I have to use `create` if there are any relationships otherwise I have to use `populate`, aren't there?

Comment: @edem no, no, no. It's not nearly that complicated. You use `create` to insert one thing into table1. You use `populate` to insert multiple things.

Answer (score 0):

as added information and a precaution:

insert always works ( and usually as expected ). You can use it for inserting many tables,
the issue is performance.

When inserting a large amount of data, populate is much faster. It does, however, sometimes behave strangely, so you should test it carefully ( as everything ;) ). Normally, it works fine, though, and when you insert thousands of entries, you will notice a significant increase in speed.